# The Job menu is extremely slow

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Does anyone else find the 'Job' menu extremely slow to open? In particular this is when opening it with the intention of giving a bitizen 'No Job' and then cycling in a newer bitizen with the aim being to earn bux for giving them a dream job (not that they seem to do that every time since the last update - not sure if that's a bug or intentional). I have ~200 bitizens and ~135 levels and a Nexus 4. Everything else in the game is fast.

Comment: As far as the Bux for dream jobs goes--it's been changed. You now only get the Bux if it's the first time a slot has had a dream jobber in it, or if you're replacing a dream jobber with one of a higher skill level (the popup's wording will reflect that). 

I have found that sometimes (though still not all the time), you can remove one dream jobber, hire someone unrelated, remove that Bitizen, then hire the new dream jobber Bitizen of a lower level, and still get the Bux. Whether it's worth waiting for all those screens to open is up to you...

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue playing on an iPhone5, 136 levels and 207 bitizens. I think it's a lag due to the vast number if bitizens to load.

When cycling new bitizens into jobs, it's probably easier to employ them via their dream job level (i.e. Go to that level and evict/unemploy a bitizen, then click "hire bitizen". The most suitable bitizens appear at the top - dream jobbers first). Hope this saves you a bit of time, but I don't think there is a solution to the lag problem.

Comment: Thanks mhazeltine - you are right that's faster, but it doesn't always solve my problem. For instance right now I have three 9's in a dream job and a level 3 for that shop has arrived. So I don't want to evict a 9 in favour of a 3, so I have to go via the Jobs menu with the lag.
They just need to tune their algorithms or data structures, sure we have a few hundred bitizens but these are powerful phones and programmed efficiently there's no reason to be this slow.

Comment: I'm running the game on a HTC One on 4.4.2 kitkat android on a 1.7ghz quad core cpu and it lags even on that during assignment of jobs, the game still needs a lot of optimization across all platforms and processor types, but there is still a lot of bug fixes to iron out first, i'm sure they'll get around to it at some stage so just have to bear with it for now.

Comment: You can always select your level 9, give them "no job" and then sub in your level 3, get the bux, evict them and then add your level 9 back in.

Comment: @mhazeltine Yes, but you still have the long lag when trying to switch the level 9 bitizen to "no job".  In fact, that's exactly what the original question is complaining about.  I started noticing this lag a long time ago (probably when I had less than 100 bitzens) and I also have a fast quad-core phone.

Comment: On the iPhone version you can give them "no job" as a direct option. I haven't noticed a lag with this option. I thought you were only referring to the job option in the main in-game menu. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: From what I've found in the Android version only the way to give a bitizen 'no job' is to open the bitizen screen, click the bottom middle icon 'JOB' and then wait for the next 'NEW JOB'/'Assign A job' screen and select 'Unemployed'/'No Job'.